# Laravel 5 reset password

Tags: callback, passwords, closures, reset, laravel-5

What we have to pass, to the send argument of the following function?

Password::reset(array('email' => $input['email'], 'password' => $input['password'], 'password_confirmation' => $input['password_confirmation'], 'token' => $token), 'what we have to pass here');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to pass callback or Closure like below

```
function($user, $password)
{
     //perform reset stuff
}
```

the closure will only fires when the reset request is valid.

Comment: return Password::reset(array('email' => $input['email'], 'password' => $input['password'], 'password_confirmation' => $input['password_confirmation'], 'token' => $token), function($input['email'], $input['password']){
            $user = new User::where('email', '=', $input['email']);
            $user->password = Hash::make($input['password']);
            $user->save();
        });     -- I'm using like this, is this correct way of doing

Comment: you may do this `function($user, $password)
  {
   $user->password = bcrypt($password);
   $user->save();
  }`
laravel will automatically provides you the user instance you dont have to select the user all by yourself

Comment: by the way, laravel 5 already provides you the password reset features out of the box, take a look on PasswordController.php located in Http/Controllers/Auth/

Comment: If we are using a function as the second parameter, throws an error -  syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'

Comment: hi, mind to post your reset code here ? i have written the same thing, but i dont receive any errors

Comment: This is the code i'm using -     public function resetPassword($token){
        $input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
        return Password::reset(array('email' => $input['email'], 'password' => $input['password'], 'password_confirmation' => $input['password_confirmation'], 'token' => $token), function($user, $input['password']) { $user->password = bcrypt($input['password']); $user->save(); });
    }

Comment: you dont have to pass $input['password'] in your Closure, copy & paste
`function($user, $password) { 
      $user->password = bcrypt($password); 
      $user->save(); 
}`